# The call to Get Selection From User in Robot framework throws a display-related error

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to perform this test with robot framework where I try to get the result of a user selection

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process 
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    BuiltIn
Library    Dialogs

*** Test Cases ***
Run tests
    ${testMode}=   Get test mode  

*** Keywords ***

Get test mode
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${options}=   Create List   OPTION_A   OPTION_B
    ${testMode}=   Get Selection From User   Select Test Mode   ${options}    
    [Return]  ${testMode}
```

Where I get the following error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

On the other hand, if you set the variable manually via:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Or

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Even adding to the robot file

```
Set Environment Variable  DISPLAY  ${0}
```

I get the following error:

```
TclError: couldn't connect to display "0"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can perform this operation in another way?

Comment: Can you describe your system? What operating system are you running? Also, can you modify your code so that it is possible to run it and reproduce your problem? Your current code fails because the `Get Selection From User` keyword is not found.

Comment: Getting error about missing DISPLAY could mean that the user is running Wayland and with quick search i didnt find any verification if python's Tk works on Wayland..